# html input field width limit

Tags: input, width, field, limit

I'm looking for a way to limit (clip) the string users can enter into a html input field by visual length of the string not number of characters. Basically I don't want my users to be able to type any more character once the caret reached the right end of a text field. Is that even possible in html?

Comment: Not HTML, you need JavaScript to do this.

Comment: But how? Should I keep a hidden div to do the measures as the user is typing? or there's some css style or trick I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Max length to however many characters you want. For example:

`<input type="text" maxlength="25">`

Comment: I want to limit by visual length not character number. Let's say my input box has 100px width, I don't want the use to type any more character more than what that would fit within 100px of that input text box.

Comment: ok, in that case you want to use the "size" and "maxlength" together. You should be able to set them to the same value for the goal you want to achieve. I don't know of any code to use in this case other than this.

Answer (score 0):

Not in HTML but if you know JS you could try this:

Render fake input element, set `visibility: hidden;` to it.
On each change of real input do the following:

1. insert value into fake input
2. measure fake input width
3. if width is more than max width, set previous value into both inputs (you have to record previous input value on each change), so basically revert last valid value.